# tooltip edit target set to 2nd field

Tags: html

I have one tooltip edit and I am enabling two input fields using class attribute. Since I am enabling 2 input fields, the control directly goes to the 2nd input field (confirm_email). Is there a way to get the control to the first field? Problem is not with the JS, looking HTML solution.

```
<div class='tooltip-container'>
    <a class="tooltip-tip tooltip-edit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" target-field=".emailEdit" data-theme="a"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    <input disabled='disabled' class='emailEdit' type="email" name="emails.PERSONAL.address" tabindex="3" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div>
    <input disabled='disabled' class='emailEdit' type="email" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" tabindex="4" placeholder="confirm">
</div>
```

```
function(event) {
    event && event.preventDefault();
    var targetSelector = $(event.currentTarget).attr("target-field");
    var inputField = this.$el.find(targetSelector);

    inputField.textinput('enable').focus();


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try setting autofocus atttribute on the first field..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi it didn't help. :(

Comment: I didn't get a HTML solution, but got one using jQuery. I used first().focus() on the target field. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used first().focus() on the target field. Hope it helps someone.